# More efficient - multiple SQL queries or one query and process in php?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a php application showing 3 tables of data, each from the same MySQL table. Each record has an integer field named status which can have values 1, 2 or 3. Table 1 shows all records with status = 1, Table 2 showing status = 2 and table 3 showing status = 3.

To achieve this three MySQL queries could be run using WHERE to filter by status, iterating through each set of results once to populate the three tables.

Another approach would be to select all from the table and then iterate through the same set of results once for each table, using php to test the value of status each time.

Would one of these approaches be significantly more efficient than the other? Or would one of them be considered better practice than the other?

Comment: no way to say: benchmark both methods and choose the best. running fewer queries is almost always a good thing, but if the post-processing necessary to convert your one-query-to-get-them-all data set into three separate sets is painful/involved, then try separate queries.

Comment: I would go for the get all approach and order the records by status. This way only one query action will be performed. But always do a benchmark test as Marc B suggests.

Comment: There are only a few very rare cases with joins on multiple very large tables where PHP array functions can be faster than mysql. But even then, it depends on the tables, the query and used indizes. Best approach allways is to try and compare results.

Comment: PHP is incredibly slow, and it's almost always better to do it in SQL, if you can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, it's better to filter on the RDBMS side so you can reduce the amount of data you need to transfer.

Transferring data from the RDBMS server over the network to the PHP client is not free. Networks have a capacity, and you can generate so much traffic that it becomes a constraint on your application performance.

For example, recently I helped a user who was running queries many times per second, each generating 13MB of result set data. The queries execute quickly on the server, but they couldn't get the data to his app because he was simply exhausting his network bandwidth. This was a performance problem that didn't happen during his testing, because when he ran one query at a time, it was within the network capacity.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the second method you connect with database only once, thus it's more efficient.
And even if it wasn't, it's more elegant that way IMO.

Of course there are some situations that it would be better to connect three times (eg. getting info from this query would be complicated), but for most of the cases I would do it the second way.

Comment: Why would you connect three times to query three tables?

Answer (score 0):

I would create a store procedure that return all the fields you need pre-formatted, no more, no less.

And then just loop on php without calling any other table.

This way you run only 1 query, and you only get the bytes you need. So same bandwidth, less http request = more performance.